# Show document libraries as tabs in web part

Tags: document-library

I have six document libraries with folders, sub folders and documents in them. I am trying to show them as tabs in a page by adding a web part to the page. Is there any way I can do this using javascript or jquery. I am using SharePoint 2010. Are there any snippets which could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try jquery ui tabs https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: tiago duarte I am looking for something automated here in the link it is showing that i have to add manually the libray names. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting here it might be useful for others.I just followed this link and it has done my job much easier. Thanks.
[enter link description here](http://www.markrackley.net/2014/11/25/sharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs2-0/)